# Impossible to get a root submodule working on Git

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I've create a submodule in my repository root in a specific folder.

I can see the submodule is well registered in .git/.gitmodules and in .gitmodules, but I can't get it working.

I can't see it if I make a git submodule status or if I make an update.

Git can't just see this submodule (others are working well).

Do you have any trail ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Did you make a `git submodule update`

Comment: Did you move the original repository after creating the submodule, or run it Windows? There are problems like this with submodules created with 1.7.8 and 1.7.9 (this is fixed in 1.7.10)

Comment: An update change nothing, Git just can't see the submodule when I'm running the git submodule command. I haven't move the repo since I've started the development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git was not able to recognize the submodule, whatever I do.

Without any modifications, I've just :

1. Delete the submodule folder
2. Add the submodule

The submodule now works correctly.

Note that Git doesn't add a new submodule, he has just recognize the submodule as it should.

Thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 0):

One idea - you're trying to add an empty repo as submodule. You need to have at lease one commit in submodule, because it is linked by commit id. Try to execute this command in root repo:

```
git ls-tree HEAD -r
```

Do you see your submodule in results? The line should look like this:

```
160000 commit 72a0f63227341c35af566de0d6d4a76797ba22b2  my_submodule_dir
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can see these lines, but I've one of them for every file of my submodule. Any idead on what happened ? Note that the repo of the submodule is full of commits.

Comment: The key moment is that object type in tree must be "commit", this means a submodule. For normal files/folders you see "tree" or "blob" type. You can try to find it with grep, like this:
git ls-tree HEAD -r | grep " commit "

Comment: P.S. If submodule is not empty, then my original suggestion is wrong

Comment: Submodule are not empty, I can see each file of the submodule with git ls-tree HEAD -r

Comment: Submodule is a completely standalone repository with it's own history and tree. So when you execute 'git ls-tree HEAD -r' in root repo, you sholdn't see files in submodule. If you see them, then git doesn't think of this folder as of submodule. I would try to delete it completely and add again with 'git submodule add'

Answer (score 0):

Another case where git submmodule status does not see (fully) a submodule is when said submodule just got created (init, but not updated yet)

That is problematic, because there was a bug fixed with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) :"`git submodule status`" did not check the symbolic revision name it computed for the submodule HEAD is not the NULL, and threw it at `printf` routines, which has been corrected.

See [commit 0b5e2ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b5e2ea7cf3b0fd0f4339b7c8b69cb8c5853c0cd) (18 Apr 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0cd58d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cd58d8ba9aa562dd3c039af9565f61a14da03b8), 08 May 2018)</sup>

> ### `submodule--helper`: don't print `null` in '`submodule status`'
>
> The function `compute_rev_name()` can return `NULL` sometimes (e.g. right
>   after '`submodule init`').
>   The current code makes '`submodule status`' print this:
>
> ```
> 19d97bf5af05312267c2e874ee6bcf584d9e9681 sha1collisiondetection ((null))
> ```
>
> This ugly '`null`' adds no value to the user using this command.
>   More importantly, `printf()` on some platform can't handle NULL as a string
>   and will crash instead of printing '`(null)`'.
>
> Check for this and skip printing this part (the alternative is
>   printing '`(n/a)`' or something but I think that is just noise).